# Count the numbers of a random generator in C

Tags: c

My code generates a random number between 1 and 6 for 1000 times and I need to count how many times each number appeared in percentage. My problem is that it is, sometimes, generating negative percentages and it is surpassing 100%. I also must use a `switch`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, n, max = 6;
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6;
    float total1, total2, total3, total4, total5, total6;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        n = rand() % max + 1; 
        switch (n) {
          case 1:
            num1 += 1;
          case 2:
            num2 += 1;
          case 3:
            num3 += 1;
          case 4:
            num4 += 1;
          case 5:
            num5 += 1;
          case 6:
            num6 += 1;
        }
    }
    total1 = num1 / 100;
    printf("Times 1 appeared: %f\n", total1);
    total2 = num2 / 100;
    printf("Times 2 appeared: %f\n", total2);
    total3 = num3 / 100;
    printf("Times 3 appeared: %f\n", total3);
    total4 = num4 / 100;
    printf("Times 4 appeared: %f\n", total4);
    total5 = num5 / 100;
    printf("Times 5 appeared: %f\n", total5);
    total6 = num6 / 100;
    printf("Times 6 appeared: %f\n", total6);
}
```

Comment: The `switch` code is missing `break;` statements. So when say `1` is rolled, *all* the `case` statements will execute, and all the counters will increment. Note too, that `num1/100` is doing *integer division* so there is no point assigning the result to a `float`. You need `num1/100.0` (or even `num1/10.0`)

Comment: Why not use an array to keep track of the frequency of each number instead?

Comment: ... to obtain the percentage (which is `num * 100 / 1000.0`)

Comment: @SteveSummit Or the instructor is clever by introducing one concept at a time. If the next topic of the class is to reduce repetetive code, that's a good lesson, and the switch statement is an obvious candidate for that.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems:

- Several values were not initialized to 0. This needs to happen explicitly.
- The switch cases had *fallthrough*. Landing on, e.g.,  `case 1` meant that the execution continued through the other cases below it.
- The totals were computed using *integer division* instead of floating point division, leading to a lack of precision.
- The decimal point for the totals was in the wrong place.

The improved code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, n, max = 6;
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0, num5 = 0, num6 = 0;    
    float total1 = 0.0F, total2 = 0.0F, total3 = 0.0F, total4 = 0.0F, total5 = 0.0F, total6 = 0.0F;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        n = rand() % max + 1; 
        switch (n)
        {
        case 1:
            num1 += 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            num2 += 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            num3 += 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            num4 += 1;
            break;
        case 5:
            num5 += 1;
            break;
        case 6:
            num6 += 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    total1 = num1/10.0F;
    printf("Times 1 appeared: %f\n", total1);
    total2 = num2/10.0F;
    printf("Times 2 appeared: %f\n", total2);
    total3 = num3/10.0F;
    printf("Times 3 appeared: %f\n", total3);
    total4 = num4/10.0F;
    printf("Times 4 appeared: %f\n", total4);
    total5 = num5/10.0F;
    printf("Times 5 appeared: %f\n", total5);
    total6 = num6/10.0F;
    printf("Times 6 appeared: %f\n", total6);
}
```

The code could be much more compact while achieving the same results. In C17:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_BINS 6

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int number_of_iterations = 1000U;
    unsigned counters[NUMBER_OF_BINS] = {0U};

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < number_of_iterations; ++i)
        ++counters[rand() % NUMBER_OF_BINS];

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NUMBER_OF_BINS; ++idx)
        printf("Times %zu appeared: %f\n", idx + 1, counters[idx] * 100.0F / number_of_iterations);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It worked now :) . I thought of using an array too, but the exercise needed a switch...

Comment: `%lu` might not be appropriate for `idx + 1` that has type `size_t`. The correct conversion specifier is `%zu`, but some C libraries are still not C99 compliant, so you should just use `int` for the index values and `%d`.

Comment: Good catch! Thank you. I've updated the answer.

Comment: The random numbers are biased. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974

Comment: @RolandIllig True. I consider it outside the scope of this question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to use an array of ints to store the frequency of each number, if you could avoid the use of `switch` of course ,since you are dealing with a small range , **1 - 6**, it can save you a lot of time. Should look like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 6

int main(void)
{
    int i, n;
    int num[MAX] = {0}; /* initialize to 0 */

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        n = rand() % MAX + 1;

        num[n - 1]++; /* since arrays start from 0 , decrement by one to avoid overflow */
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ΜΑΧ; i++)
    {
        printf("number %d, appeared :  %.1f%%\n", i + 1, ((float)num[i] * 100.0f / 1000.0f));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `max` variable? `6` is hardcoded in the rest of the code.

Comment: I agree this is a better approach, but the OP wrote: *I also must use a switch.*

Comment: @chqrlie Indeed, MAX better be a directive, and yes I should have added that this is an alternative if `switch` could be avoided.